# Ejecutar dos o mas funciones al presionar dos teclas con KeyDown

Tags: javascript

Hola que tal? Estoy tratando de crear una especie de sintetizador y me gustaría saber si se puede tocar dos o mas notas al mismo tiempo al presionar varias teclas, ya que al hacerlo , solo me ejecuta una sola función.
Codigo:

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    } else {
        element["on" + eventName] = callback;
    }
}
```

Con esta función y dos addEvent, uno con keydown y otro keyup. Se presionan las notas según la letra que se le asignó, pero solo una a la vez.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

**AddEvent de Key Down resumido:**

```
addEvent(document, "keydown", function (e) {
    

     if(!teclaPresionada  ){
    
        if(event.keyCode == 68){
          console.log("Tecla Presionada");
          document.getElementById("notado").style.background="red"
         document.getElementById("suenado").play();
        
        }

    if(event.keyCode == 70){
          console.log("Tecla Presionada");
          document.getElementById("notare").style.background="blue"
          document.getElementById("suenare").play();
        }
    }
```

**AddEvent de Key Up:**

```
 addEvent(document, "keyup", function (e) {
    
      if(teclaPresionada){
        
        var todo = document.getElementsByClassName("nota")
        console.log("Tecla Liberada");
        for(var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++){
        todo[i].style.background = null;
    }
        
        teclaPresionada = false;
      }
      
    });
```

Comment: En principio no habría problema para hacer lo que quieres, el problema no está en esta parte del código. Si crearas un [mcve] quizá podríamos ayudarte a resolverlo

Comment: Hola! Ahi edite mi pregunta, no agregue todos los keycode para no usar tanto codigo, pero es uno por cada nota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la causa es que tienes una variable global (`teclaPresionada`) que no permite más de una tecla presionada a la vez. Yo he podido reproducir dos audios a la vez usando botones o las teclas A y B, por ejemplo:

```js
const audio0 = document.getElementById('sound0');
const audio1 = document.getElementById('sound1');

const A = document.getElementById('ab');
const B = document.getElementById('bb');

A.addEventListener('click',() => audio0.play());
B.addEventListener('click',() => audio1.play());

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  console.log(event.code);
  if (event.code == 'KeyA'){
    console.log("Tecla A Presionada");
    audio0.play();
  }

  if (event.code == 'KeyB'){
    console.log("Tecla B Presionada");
    audio1.play();
  }
});
```

```html
<audio id="sound0">
  <source crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/95/95332_1579599-lq.mp3"/>
</audio>
<audio id="sound1">
  <source crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/95/95332_1579599-lq.mp3"/>
</audio>
<button id="ab">A</button>
<button id="bb">B</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto, use el metodo de addEventListener y me funciono! Muchas gracias

Comment: Tu código parece sacado de un tutorial antiguo, con código que funciona en versiones antiguas de IE. Por ejemplo, usar event.keyCode está desaconsejado desde hace años. Y addEventListener está ya soportado por todos los navegadores

Comment: Estuve buscando alternativas a event.keyCode pero no encontré ninguna que funcione como tal